# Is there a policy for questions/discussions which lead to a new discovery?

Tags: discussion

I believe that a forum like this provides one with the possibility of sourcing a wide spectrum of engineering know-how thus it could be a useful and efficient medium for developing projects or prototypes from concepts and ideas that require a wide range of specializations in different fields of engineering.

Is there policy in Engineering Stack Exchange dealing with situations where a question and its discussion result in discovery of practical applications in engineering not implemented to date? Does the issue of intellectual property need to be specifically established amongst the different people that decide to work together in the development of an engineering concept which results from a discussion?

Comment: Policy for *what*?  If it's a good question for the site, then it can be posted here.  That decision is made usually before there are any answers, so it can't be know at the time what the content of answers may be.  Other than closing/deleting/voting, what choice do we have regarding what to do about a particular question.

Comment: I disagree that this site could be "useful and efficient" for developing prototypes. It's also not a discussion forum. This is a question and answer site. It's not a place for brainstorming design or troubleshooting ideas. That's not to say someone creating a new invention couldn't use this as a resource, but it should be on a specific issue or problem they have. Do we have systems in place to facilitate work groups on projects? No, that's not at all what we do here.

Comment: @Juan Once is it posted on here, it is in the public domain (at least in the US).  As such, it is governed by standard intellectual property laws.  A post on here could be used, for example, as prior art to a patent.

Comment: @Juan If you really want an answer to this question, you can make it a little more generic and post it on [law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/).  A somewhat similar question that [I posted there](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/596/what-legal-liability-does-ones-participation-on-stack-exchange-carry) was very well received.